# Gmail PHP IMAP network is unreachable

Tags: php, gmail, imap

Why not works this? I read some question in stackoverflow, but not solved my problem.

My code:

```
<?php

    function mailCount ( $host, $login, $passwd ) {

        $mbox = imap_open ( $host, $login, $passwd, OP_READONLY ) or die ( imap_last_error () );
        $mail = '';

        if ( $mail = imap_check ( $mbox ) ) {

            return $mail -> Nmsgs;

        }

    }

    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
    $username = '********@gmail.com';
    $password = '********';

    $count = mailCount ( $hostname, $username, $password );

    print $count;

?>
```

The error message: "Can't connect to imap.gmail.com,993: Network is unreachable"

I visited the https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps link and turn on and access the IMAP in https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/fwdandpop try.

Comment: Firewalls. Firewalls. Firewalls.  Check with your IT/host provider/router/OS etc.  IMAP is blocked on a lot of networks because its intended for end users.

Comment: Dear Max, Thanks. It works, but settings: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha